# Testnet eWallet?

Tags: services, websites, e-wallet, testnet

Is there any eWallet available that works on the TestNet? I want to test some payments and so forth and sometimes I want to have an access to an online wallet, so I don't need to hassle with installing Bitcoin on various machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have recently created [a Faucet and an eWallet for the TestNet](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/). It is very basic, but serves its purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, every time I try to create a TestNet wallet there and then request a tiny amount to it (0.27 BTC looks like at last load), I get an error that reads: "We are sorry, but an error has occurred.

API error 5 (urlfetch: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED)

Back to main page.

Server code created by ThePiachu."

Comment: OK, seems to be working now. I tweeted @ThePiachu so maybe he fixed! One thing I noticed was that when the CAPTCHA was just the simple numbers on the side of a house (i.e., to use humans to improve Google Maps), the request did not work. However, once they were actual letters/words, they did. Could be entirely coincidental ..

Answer (score 6):

I built a dedicated testnet wallet during a weekend hackathon

http://testnetwallet.com

Answer (score 2):

Andreas Schildbach's [Bitcoin Wallet for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet) comes in [a second variant that uses testnet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet_test), so you can have it on your phone or tablet with no hassle.